# Shortcut homescreen, how to send extras

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut

I've read somewhere (but I can't find it anymore) that it should be possible to send extras from a shortcut on the device home screen. I created successfully a shortcut, but `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` gives a nullpointer.

I create the shortcut as follows:

```
   Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                        Shortcut_Activity.class);

                shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

                Intent addIntent = new Intent();
                addIntent
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
                addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);
                addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                        Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this.getApplicationContext(),
                                R.drawable.ic_shortcut));
                addIntent.putExtra("ID", id); //THIS IS THE EXTRA DATA I WANT TO ATTACH
                addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
                this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Is it possible? And ifso, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found here: http://www.joulespersecond.com/2010/04/android-tip-effective-intents/

Fortunately, there’s a solution. The better way is to put the row ID as part of a URI, rather than as a part of an extra. So the previous code becomes something like this:

```
void returnShortcut(int rowId, String shortcutName) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowInfoActivity.class);
    i.setData(ContentUris.withAppendedId(BASE_URI, rowId));
    Intent shortcut = new Intent();
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, i);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, shortcutName);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, shortcut);
    finish();
}
```

BASE_URI can be anything, but it should be something that’s specific to your application. The point is that the Data URI is used in determining whether or not two intents are equal, so the system will end up creating a new Activity for this, even if the same Activity with different data is on your task’s stack.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have achieved it, Here is the code

```
private void addShortcut() {
    //Adding shortcut for MainActivity 
    //on Home screen
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            HOMESHORTCUT.class);
    //Set Extra
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("extra", "shortCutTest ");

    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);


}
//GET Extra in HOMESHORTCUT activity.
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mTextExtra=new TextView(this);
        Bundle bundel=getIntent().getExtras();
        String getExString=getIntent().getExtras().getString("extra");
        mTextExtra.setText(getExString);
        setContentView(mTextExtra);
    }
```

Comment: but this code will crash if the bundle, here named extras ( for whatever reason ) is null nevertheless

Comment: just in case you still have null exception, **DELETE old shortcuts** and let new ones to create if you're using `addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);`